# first query attribute is read from the url, but the second one is not | c# blazor

Tags: c#, url, get, blazor

I am currently programming a blazor application and would like to read attributes from the url. a form sends 2 attributes into the url, 'search' and 'sorting'. The first attribute, 'search' is read correctly from the url, but the second 'sorting' is not. this is and always remains null. Here is my code.

```
[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public string? search { get; set; }

[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public string? sorting { get; set; }

public void ExampleMethod()
{
    string searchAtt = search;

    string sortingAtt = sorting;
}
```

The example method is executed in the 'OnInitialized' method.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ExampleMethod();
}
```

My form looks like this.

```
<form action="" method="get" class="m-4">
<div class="mb-4">
    <label for="search" class="mb-1 text-white">Nach Nachnamen suchen...</label>
    <input name="search" value="@search" id="search" placeholder="Suchen..." type="text" class="form-control border-2"/>
</div>

<div class="mb-4">
    <label for="select" class="mb-1 text-white">Sortieren nach...</label>
    <select name="sorting" id="select" class="form-select border-2">
        @if (sorting == "vn")
        {
            <option value="nn">Nachname</option>
            <option selected value="vn">Vorname</option>
            <option value="at">Abteilung</option>
        }
        else if (sorting == "at")
        {
            <option value="nn">Nachname</option>
            <option value="vn">Vorname</option>
            <option selected value="at">Abteilung</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option selected value="nn">Nachname</option>
            <option value="vn">Vorname</option>
            <option value="at">Abteilung</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="mb-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-2">Anwenden</button>
</div>
```

After executing my form the url looks like following: https://localhost:44346/?search=sa&sorting=vn

But as you can see here, the 'search' attribute has a value but the 'sorting' value is still null.

[search attribute is passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlori.png)

[sorting attribute is passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nURl.png)

Comment: Can you show your get method?

Comment: @viveknuna hi vivek nune, thanks for your comment, i really don't understand, which get method you mean. the attributes are read from the query with the 'SupplyParameterFromQuery' tag. they dont need a get.

Comment: I mean when you hit enter to the URL which methods get called?

Comment: @viveknuna only the 'OnInitialize' method of the razor page, this has the consequence, that the 'ExampleMethod' gets executed.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `[SupplyParameterFromQuery]` to `[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "sorting")]`? Maybe it helps.

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt Good thought but i've already tried it :(.

Comment: The problem was that I used the SupplyParameterFromQuery tag on a razor page that was called from a parent and wasn't loaded as page in the browser. In the parent, the search was also defined, but the sort was not.

This is how I had it in the parent:

`<ListUsers search="@searchStatement" />`

And this is how it should have been in the parent:
`<ListUsers search="@searchStatement" sort="@sortStatement"  />`

Answer (score 2):

`[SupplyParameterFromQuery]` will use the first query parameter matching the type of the parameter. Here both parameters use the same type (nullable string) so you will always be assigned the first matching query parameter.

To work around this issue, use the optional Name argument to specify the actual name of the query parameter, as stated by Jonas Weinhardt:

```csharp
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name="search")]
    public string? search { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name="sorting")]
    public string? sorting { get; set; }
```

By doing this you will also be able to use parameter names that are different from the query parameter name, typically you would use standard CamelCase for the blazor component parameters, so:

```csharp
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name="search")]
    public string? Search { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name="sorting")]
    public string? Sorting { get; set; }
```